# BFilter not removing the search filter from datatable

Tags: javascript, vb.net, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a htm page somewhat like this.

```
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <div class="span12">    
        $NewReport$    
    </div>
</div>
```

Where NewReport is a grid thats populated using a datatable.

```
view.Replace("$NewReport$", grid.Render("NewReport", model.NewReportDataTable, GetNewReportGridColumns(model)))
```

On rendering it appears with the search filter which I don't want.
I know that bFilter property could be set to False to turn the search filter off.
But I am not sure where to use it.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you to solve issue. There might be version issue for datatable.

If DataTables >= 1.10 use:

```
$('table').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, info: false});
```

If DataTables < 1.10 use:

```
$('table').dataTable({bFilter: false, bInfo: false});
```

you can also check pure CSS solution:

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }
```

Comment: Just for clarification, as I am not very good with JS, in the script of the htm, I am supposed to use $('#NewReport').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, info: false}); .
Will it not be a problem that the grid is being populated via the code and there isnt an actual table in the htm itself?

Comment: @BWashishtha like you said you have used bFilter: false , so can you try to use searching: false in the same way. it should work